# Change output of a field with PHP field?

Tags: views

I'm constructing a view in Drupal 7 with a field called "Content: Fruit". If the value of that field is "lemon", I want to change the output to "citrus". How can I accomplish this?

Here's what I tried:

First, I excluded the "Content: Fruit" field from the display. Then I added a "Global: PHP" field after it where, in the "Value code" section, I added:

`return $row->field_fruit;`

Then in the "Output code" section I added:

```
<?php  
    if ($value == 'lemon') {
        print 'citrus';
    }
?>
```

This doesn't work. The value of `$value` seems to be the node ID ("nid").

Thought this would be straightforward... what am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have the logic a little backwards:

Value Code:

`if($row->field_fruit == 'lemon') return 'citrus';`

Output Code:

`<?php print $value; ?>`

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful... but it still is only outputting the NID for the value of `$row->field_fruit`.

Comment: then there's probably something wrong with your field - the above works which means the problem is upstream, either the field or other elements at play. Is the Global PHP field AFTER the field_fruit field in the list?

Comment: Yep, it's last in the list. Interestingly, the only field that seems to work is the Title field. All other field that I've tested simply return the NID. What could be wrong with the field. It's a fairly standard text field. Thanks!

Comment: do you implement a hook_query_alter() anywhere? do you have aggregation turned on? do you have any rewrite rules in places?

Comment: Not that I know of, no, and no.

Comment: getting weirder by the minute...does the field_fruit output correctly on its own?  if so, try a new test View (no extras, just a vanilla View), only the title and field_fruit and try the php again

Answer (score 0):

use devel's dpm() to find the field you need in the view. drill down through the variables and once you found the value you are looking for double click it to give you the code suggestion for that field. The php module is funky as hell and needs to be updated.

`$row->field_fruit` SHOULD give you the NID, that's normal functionality (too bad it doesn't reflect in the view php docs hey? lol)

try:

```
$data->field_field_fruit[0]['raw']['value'];
```

so

```
<?php
  if($data->field_field_fruit[0]['raw']['value'] == 'lemon' ){
    print 'citrus';
  }
?>
```

tada